# Function Toggle not working onf Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, image, firefox, toggle

I have no idea whats going on with this but I have a website with this html:

```
<button id="mute"><input type="image" src="img/stop.png" class="stop" onclick="toggleStop(this);"/></button>
        <button id="mute2"><input type="image" src="img/sonido.png" class="mute stop" onclick="toggle(this);"/></button>
```

And I'm trying to toggle the image when ON CLICK with this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(el){
    if(el.className!="mute")
    {
        el.src='img/mute.png';
        el.className="mute";
    }
    else if(el.className=="mute")
    {
        el.src='img/sonido.png';
        el.className="audio";
    }
    return false;
}  
</script>
<script>
function toggleStop(event){
    if(el.className!="play")
    {
        el.src='img/play.png';
        el.className="play";
    }
    else if(el.className=="play")
    {
        el.src='img/stop.png';
        el.className="stop";
    }
    return false;
}  
</script>
```

It works perfect on Chrome, but it doesnt work on Firefox. I have no clue what's wrong. Sadly I'm no developer, so I do what I can searching on the Internet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way this code, as posted, can run under Chrome (or Firefox or any other browser.)

I tried turning it into a snippet but had to make a number of changes to get it usable ... then I stopped trying.

Main issues:

You can't nest an `<input>` instead of a `<button>`.  Use one or the other.

If you use `<button>`, it should be `<button type="button">` to keep it from acting as a submit button and reloading your form.

Your code is broken.

```
function toggleStop(event){
    if(el.className!="play")
```

There is no element `el` and an error is generated.

The first rule of JavaScript work: ALWAYS, ALWAYS check the error console.

Answer (score 0):

So...I took what you said about an INPUT inside an BUTTON and I just delete the button and use an  isntead and now it works on both browsers.

Thanks a lot Jeremy!